# SharePoint Nested If Statement to add days to a date if condition is met

Tags: date, sharepoint, nested-if

I have a SharePoint Document library and need a calculated column to store a due date.
My existing columns are "Requires Follow Up?" which is a Yes/No field, and a "JPE Date" which is a date field.  If Requires Follow Up? is equal to Yes, I want the due date to be 7 days after the JPE Date. If Requires Follow Up? is equal to No or null I don't want a date in this field and would accept a blank, null or hyphen instead of a date.

I have tried many iterations of the following formulas:

IF(OR([Requires Follow Up?]="No",ISBLANK([Requires Follow Up?])),"-",IF([Requires Follow Up?]="Yes",[JPE Date]+7,"-")

=IF(([Requires Follow Up?])="No","-",IF(([Requires Follow Up?])="Yes",DATE(YEAR([JPE Date]),MONTH([JPE Date]),DAY([JPE Date])+7),IF(ISBLANK(([Requires Follow Up?])),"","")))

I feel like my reference to "Yes" is the issue, but replacing "Yes" with TRUE also doesn't work. I also tried to employ  <>"Yes" but am not certain if this means "not equal to" in this context.

I have been working from an Excel formula that performs perfectly every time: =IF(E5="No","-",IF(E5="Yes",D5+7,IF(ISBLANK(E5),"0","1")))  where E5 is the Required Follow Up? and D5 is the JPE date.

I am working in Notepad and copying into the SharePoint formula field so I think my quote marks are the correct characters.

Can anyone suggest better or improved syntax or other approaches to accomplish same? My research thus far tells me I need the square brackets because my column headers contain spaces, but this is new to me so I may not have understood that correctly.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works:

```
=IF(([Requires Follow Up?]),DATE(YEAR([JPE Date]),MONTH([JPE Date]),DAY([JPE Date])+7),"")
```

thanks to Ryan at Pentalogic

http://blog.pentalogic.net/2015/06/sharepoint-calculated-column-formula-with-yes-no-boolean-fields/